# React Grid Layout - Grid Item shown on screen even though not within layout

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am using react-grid-layout to try to make a resizable grid. I also tried adding the functionality to remove grid items. However, upon removal of grid item (which in actual fact just removes that item from the layout object passed in, the grid item would then change to the smallest size possible, but still stay on the screen. Is there any reason for this? enter image description here

Before removing from layout

[image]

After removing from layout

[image]

Here is the layout object:

before

```
            { i: 'card', x: 0, y: 0, w: 5, h: 8, minH: 8, },
            { i: 'calendar', x: 0, y: 8, w: 5, h: 25 },
            { i: 'forecast', x: 5, y: 0, w: 5, h: 18 },
            { i: 'workflow', x: 5, y: 18, w: 2, h: 15 },
            { i: 'activities', x: 7, y: 18, w: 3, h: 15 },
```

after removing

```
            { i: 'calendar', x: 0, y: 8, w: 5, h: 25 },
            { i: 'forecast', x: 5, y: 0, w: 5, h: 18 },
            { i: 'workflow', x: 5, y: 18, w: 2, h: 15 },
            { i: 'activities', x: 7, y: 18, w: 3, h: 15 },
```

after removing and when onLayoutChange is called

```
            { i: 'card', x: 0, y: 0, w: 1, h: 1 },
            { i: 'calendar', x: 0, y: 1, w: 5, h: 25 },
            { i: 'forecast', x: 5, y: 0, w: 5, h: 18 },
            { i: 'workflow', x: 5, y: 18, w: 2, h: 15 },
            { i: 'activities', x: 7, y: 18, w: 3, h: 15 },
```

Why is it that the removed grid item still appears on the screen? I removed it onClick of the 'X' button, by removing that grid item from the layout object, however, right after it is removed, the onLayoutChange method is called, and it adds that 'card' back into the layout object, just with the smallest size. Is there any reason for this? I am new to using react-grid-layout, do let me know if I did anything wrong!

Here is my code for the grid

```
const layout = useSelector(state => state.layout.project.pre_layout)
// this layout is the layout object shown above, taken from redux store

const onLayoutChange = (layout, layouts) => {
    console.log(layout);
    console.log(layouts);
    dispatch({ type: "LAYOUT_ONCHANGE", layout: layouts, page: 'project' })
    // this dispatch updates the redux store with the new layout
}

        <ResponsiveGridLayout className="layout" layouts={layout}
            onLayoutChange={(layout, layouts) =>
                onLayoutChange(layout, layouts)
            }
            breakpoints={{ lg: 1200, md: 996, sm: 768, xs: 480, xxs: 0 }}
            cols={{ lg: 12, md: 10, sm: 6, xs: 4, xxs: 2 }}
            rowHeight={row_height}
            compactType={'vertical'}
            preventCollision={false}>
        /* content here */
        </ResponsiveGridLayout>
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but I've just encountered this myself so figured I'd put my findings!

If you just remove the layout details for an item but leave it in the content - it'll stay on the grid but reset back to default position and dimension.

To remove an item completely you'll need to remove it from both the layout and the content. Content being whatever you're displaying in /* content here */